# how to add a icon to Tree.TreeNode

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, antd

I flow [Use in create-react-app](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app) to create a react app with antd, but how to add a icon to a Tree.TreeNode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since TreeNode[title] can be any ReactElement (See it's doc https://ant.design/components/tree/#TreeNode-props), so that you can write like this `<TreeNode key="theKey" title={<span><Icon type="link" />The title</span>} />`